# Ruby on Rails root to: 'static_pages#home' not linking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

When I click on the home button, Rails is directing to the default "Welcome aboard You’re riding Ruby on Rails!" page that loads after you've first installed ROR. Not sure why the file located in app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb is not loading.

Here is my routes file.

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
    member do
        get :following, :followers
    end
end
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

root to: 'static_pages#home'

match '/static_pages/home', :to =>'static_pages#home'

# resource to get the standard actions for sessions
match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete `index.html` from the `public` folder :)